# nginx capture/forward header from upstream server

Tags: nginx, server, header

can you please tell what configuration are needed in order to capture header response from upstream server or can you please point me to some documentation. It's possible to forward the response to another upstream server.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward request headers from nginx proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751313/forward-request-headers-from-nginx-proxy-server)

Comment: I have looked over the question that you mentioned however I haven't found the answer I seek. Moreover the question is old.