# Is There Any Ways to Get the Real Client IP Address on Nginx Reverse proxy Without Changing any things on server side

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I set a server **130.153.32.231 (Nginx)** as a reverse_proxy for **www.mysite.com** (Apache) they both had separate server, The problem was how can I get the user real IP address that access 130.153.32.231 and pass it to www.mysite.com without changing anythings in www.mysite.com, because what I can see all user shows 130.153.32.231 not the real IP.

Already try http_realip_module and proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For but none of this do the job, any ones know how to fix this..

Comment: What problems do you get with X-Forwarded-For? It is designed to do what you seem to want to achieve.

Comment: The site www.mysite.com still catch the user ip as 130.153.32.231, not the user ip instead

Comment: So on ngnix side you are using something like `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr` and on the site www.mysite.com you are seeing the 'X-Forwarded-For' header set to 130.153.32.231 rather than the $remote_addr?

Comment: yes that was happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the nginx side make sure you are passing through the remote address to the X-Forwarded-For header using something like:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr
```

Then on the Apache side use mod_remoteip ([docs here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html)) to take the IP address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header:

```
RemoteIPInternalProxy 130.153.32.231
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

You also need to tell Apache to trust the proxy (the RemoteIPInternalProxy does this).

Comment: so this cannot be done if we didn't makes any change on the apache site? because I doesn't have accessed on the www.mysite.com

Comment: I don’t believe so as this information isn’t passed from nginx to Apache - Apache works it out from the IP that it received the data from. You would need to make modifications to the Apache side to change this.

Comment: Also check if you are running nginx at a docker container inside a docker swarm cluster, if yes, then you will have to follow [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415595/docker-swarm-get-real-ip-client-host-in-nginx/50592485#50592485)