# ASP.NET Core Minimal API not picking up request headers when hosted on VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, entity-framework-core, minimal-apis

So I'm running a Linux VM (DigitalOcean Droplet) to host my ASP.NET Core Minimal API, I've got one endpoint that requires a refresh token to be supplied in the header and have done so using the following parameter/annotation in the MapPost call

```
app.MapPost("/auth/refresh",
    [AllowAnonymous] async (HttpRequest request, DataContext context, [FromHeader(Name = "refresh_token") ] string refresh_token) => { functionality here }
```

But when I fill in the header and hit send on the Swagger UI, it fails to recognise the header value - only when hosted on the VM, using localhost on my PC seems to be working fine.
Gives me this error before it even steps into the function block

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Required parameter "string refresh_token" was not provided from header.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.RequiredParameterNotProvided(HttpContext httpContext, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, String source, Boolean shouldThrow)
> at lambda_method4(Closure , Object , HttpContext )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.b__0(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>
> HEADERS
>
> =======
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Host: randomtestdomain.site
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>
> Origin: https://randomtestdomain.site
>
> Referer: https://randomtestdomain.site/swagger/index.html
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> X-Forwarded-For: 175.36.206.175
>
> X-Forwarded-Proto: https
>
> sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
>
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
>
> sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
>
> Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
>
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
>
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

As pictured, I checked the network tab on Chrome to see that the header was being attached properly and it wasn't an issue with the swagger UI, all appears fine in that regard.[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tw44.png)

Also tried using app.UseForwardedHeaders() to no avail.

Let me know if more of the source is needed to discern the issue or if this might be a DNS forwarding issue or something, since I wouldn't expect it to be code-related I've kept it light but relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on headers provided looks like you are using some kind of reverse proxy in your VM setup - check if it is setup correctly to pass through all needed headers (like [here was done for Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19751313/2501279)).